# Submitting comments to Wordpress without SSL /OAuth

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl

I want to let android/iPhone users submit comments anonymously (without registering to the blog) to a self-hosted Wordpress blog.

Is there a simple, secure way to do that?

What I researched so far:

JSON API Plugin -> Works well, but no security.

WP-API -> Doesn't have Submit Comment method implemented + no security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can just use nonces to avoid XSS attacks, other then that you will obviously need your users to be logged in. Here is a simple way to do that.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-json-api-how-to-add-a-comment-or-post

**EDIT:** If you just need to be able to post the comment with their name and email address. Use it as below, but make sure you **enable  "Respond controller"** from the api settings

```
http://yourwebsite.com/api/?json=submit_comment&post_id=170&name=Omer&email=commenter@gmail.com&content=comment
```

**2nd Edit:** For securing the comments you can use nonces, if its not a built in functionality into the plugin you will have to add this functionality inside the submit_comment controller. But it would be a bit hard to generate the nonces from your android application though. A simple solution would be to wrap the existing code in a condition. Something like a base64 encoded time token.

```
if(isset($_GET['token'])){
  $token = base64_decode($_GET['token']);
  $current_time = time();
  $difference = round(abs($current_time - $token) / 60,2);//difference in minutes
  if($difference < 5){
      // Run the code thats already in submit_comment controller.
  }
}
```

Then in the REST api you can send something like

```
http://yourwebsite.com/api/?json=submit_comment&post_id=170&name=Omer&email=commenter@gmail.com&content=comment&token=BASE64_ENCODED_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Why do users need to be logged in? Can't they just fill in their email and submit the comment, as they would do it on the blog? The discussion link describes creating a post where it says that being logged in is necessary.

Comment: Will you be using this for your android application?

Comment: Yes, that is my intention. Android/iPhone app should be able to submit a comment just as they would do on the blog. It sounds like a simple feature, right?

Comment: Thanks, and now the security issue - what prevents someone from seeing what the posting url is and writing a simple loop script to submit lots of spam comments? Is there anything I can do (Except SSL / oAuth) to prevent this?

Comment: You will need to use nonces for that, nonces are like unique session ids that get expired after a few minutes, so even if someone finds the link they would need a valid nonce to be able to post the message which will only be granted from your application. Checkout the first link for more details.

Comment: The endpoint for submitting comments does not work with nonces - they are only for posts https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/#2.3.-Respond-controller-methods . I checked out the first link and in the discussion one of the responders starts talking about publishing posts, not comments, that's why nonces are mentioned.

Comment: You can use encrypted timestamps which will be valid for 5 mins, Checkout my edit.

Comment: That would be a nice workaround, I guess. Given all the constraints, doesnt sound like a bad idea.